# How can I pass an object instance in a method call in C#?

Tags: c#, pass-by-reference, class-instance-variables, method-parameters

I have a class Club which has a list _list as an argument, while 'Player' is another class ... I have this method for adding the club members, thas is implemented this way:

```
public void AddPlayer(Player p)
{
    if(_list.Contains( p)) 
        throw new Exception("The Player " + p.Name + " " + p.Surname + " is already a         member of this club!");
    _list.Add(p);
}
```

Now, when I do this in my main program:

```
Player p = new Player("Christiano", "Ronaldo", 1993);
Club club = new Club("ManUtd", coach);
club.AddPlayer(p);
```

It throws an exception that says that object reference is not set as an instance of an object.

Comment: How do you initialize the _list variable?

Comment: Please show us the code where you're initializing `_list`. I suspect it's still `null`.

Comment: In general, the best way to troubleshoot stuff like this is to set a breakpoint in the method, and then walk through it until you hit the exception. That'll usually tell you where to look.

Comment: this is my constructor for class Club : 

        public Club(string clubName, Coach mycoach) 
        { List<Player> _list = new List<Player>(); ClubName = clubName; Mycoach = mycoach; }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Constructor code grabbed from OP comment.)

In your constructor, it appears that you just initializing a local variable within that method, not the field _list.

```
public Club(string clubName, Coach mycoach) 
{ 
     List<Player> _list = new List<Player>(); 
     ClubName = clubName; 
     Mycoach = mycoach; 
}
```

Try changing

```
 List<Player> _list = new List<Player>();
```

to:

```
 _list = new List<Player>();
```

Comment: you were right! That is why all other constructors were working just fine :D I just copy pasted the whole declaration of _list! :D

thanks so much, now it works :)

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like your _list instance variable is null. Try initializing it:

```
public class Club {
    private List<Player> _players = new List<Player>();
}
```

Comment: this is my constructor for class Club :

        public Club(string clubName, Coach mycoach)
        {
            List<Player> _list = new List<Player>();
            ClubName = clubName;
            Mycoach = mycoach;
        }

Comment: @NickyName: Tormod has it right. Consider always using "this." to reference instance fields and properties. That way, you'll be guaranteed not to get this error.